# Using d3.js, how to make cylindrical liquid fill gauge?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a `cylindrical liquid fill gauge` with `correct animation.`

Error:There is problem in wave and animation in chart.

I have tried it in `plunker .`

I am attaching my plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jl2ACdmxd99I3b9539t7?p=preview

Please, help me in improving its animation and code?

```
code:-
--------------
    // The clipping wave area.
                var clipArea = d3.area()
                  .x(function(d) {
                      return waveScaleX(d.x);
                  })
                  .y0(function(d) {
                      return waveScaleY(Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * config.get("waveOffset") * -1 + Math.PI * 2 * (1 - config.get("waveCount")) + d.y * 2 * Math.PI));
                  })
                  .y1(function(d) {
                      return (fillCircleRadius * 2 + waveHeight);
                  });

                var gaugeGroupDefs = gaugeGroup.append("defs");

                var clipId = idGenerator("clipWave");
                var waveGroup = gaugeGroupDefs
                  .append("clipPath")
                  .attr("id", clipId);
                var wave = waveGroup.append("path")
                  .datum(data)
                  .attr("d", clipArea);
```

Comment: "Some" issue is not very helpful description. I would appreciate if you described it properly.

Comment: I have mentioned the error above .

Comment: There is no description of what the issue is, and once you fix your code, the issue will be gone and future readers will not be able to refer the initial problem to see if their problem applies. Unless you're willing to freeze the code you've linked as is for as long as SO will exist.